# Remove what'sThis from a dialog in pyside

Tags: python, pyside, qdialog

I have found quite a few questions about doing this in C++, but none about doing it in Python/PySide.
I want to remove the '?' button
[image]
from the top of my QDialog. I know I will use `setWindowFlags()`, however I don't know what I should pass as arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [How can I hide/delete the "?" help button on the "title bar" of a Qt Dialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81627/how-can-i-hide-delete-the-help-button-on-the-title-bar-of-a-qt-dialog) you can do this:

```
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore
app = QtGui.QApplication([])
d = QtGui.QDialog(None, QtCore.Qt.WindowSystemMenuHint | QtCore.Qt.WindowTitleHint)
d.exec_()
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't see that particular question, I don't know why.

Answer (score 8):

The following works correctly without modifying other flags:

```
self.setWindowFlags(self.windowFlags()
                    ^ QtCore.Qt.WindowContextHelpButtonHint)
```

Answer (score -1):

I create a Dialog inherited from QDialog, and write the following code in **init** function.

```
self.setWindowFlags(self.windowFlags() ^ Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
```

The question button on title bar is gone

ps. My program is based on PySide 1.2.1 and Python 3.3

Comment: qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint does not remove the what'sThis question mark, but forces the window to always be top level. You should use qt.WindowContextHelpButtonHint, as stated by Nimar above.