# PyQt4 QInputDialog and QMessageBox window flags

Tags: python, pyqt, qdialog

I am using python 2.7 and PyQt4 to make a gui; my experience is pretty limited.  I wanted to use the QInputDialog and QMessageBox objects for some of the dialogs I need.  I don't want to have the "?" in any dialogs I use.  There is an answer posted on how to do this for a similar question [How can I hide/delete the "?" help button on the "title bar" of a Qt Dialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81627/how-can-i-hide-delete-the-help-button-on-the-title-bar-of-a-qt-dialog)

That solution works for a standard QDialog.  It amounts to:

```
    message = QtGui.QDialog(self, QtCore.Qt.WindowSystemMenuHint | QtCore.Qt.WindowTitleHint)
```

This gets rid of the "?" and leaves the rest.  I am not having the same results with the other classes.  This is what I have tried for the QInput Dialog:

```
    nameDialog = QtGui.QInputDialog(self, QtCore.Qt.WindowSystemMenuHint | QtCore.Qt.WindowTitleHint)
    nameDialog = QtGui.QInputDialog(self, flags = QtCore.Qt.WindowSystemMenuHint | QtCore.Qt.WindowTitleHint)
    nameDialog = QtGui.QInputDialog(self, flags = QtCore.Qt.WindowSystemMenuHint | QtCore.Qt.WindowTitleHint | ~QtCore.Qt.WindowContextHelpButtonHint)
    nameDialog = QtGui.QInputDialog(self, flags = QtCore.Qt.WindowTitleHint | ~QtCore.Qt.WindowContextHelpButtonHint)
```

or

```
    nameDialog = QtGui.QInputDialog(self)
    nameDialog.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.WindowSystemMenuHint | QtCore.Qt.WindowTitleHint)
    nameDialog.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.WindowContextHelpButtonHint)
    nameDialog.setWindowFlags(nameDialog.windowFlags() | ~QtCore.Qt.WindowContextHelpButtonHint)
    newUser = nameDialog.getText(self, 'User change', 'Enter name:')
```

None of these produced any results.  The same thing happened no matter which line I used: the dialog shows up with the "?" just like it does when no second argument is included.

The QMessageBox gave me other problems when I tried to remove the "?".  This is what I tried:

```
    mkDialog = QtGui.QMessageBox(self, QtCore.Qt.WindowSystemMenuHint | QtCore.Qt.WindowTitleHint)
```

and

```
    mkDialog = QtGui.QMessageBox(self)
    mkDialog.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.WindowSystemMenuHint | QtCore.Qt.WindowTitleHint)
```

The first method gives me an error "argument 1 has unexpected type MainWin" (MainWin is the parent class).  The second method displays the dialog with no title bar at all.

This question was asked before, [How to remove help button on QInputDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33652685/how-to-remove-help-button-on-qinputdialog), but it got marked as a duplicate of the first question I posted.  The same solution does not work for QInputDialog or QMessageBox as QDialog so [How can I hide/delete the "?" help button on the "title bar" of a Qt Dialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81627/how-can-i-hide-delete-the-help-button-on-the-title-bar-of-a-qt-dialog) is not any help.

Any new advice would be appreciated.

Comment: For `QInputDialog`, see the [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33652685/how-to-remove-help-button-on-qinputdialog#comment55086424_33652685) to the question you already linked to.

Comment: Thank you.   I can't believe I missed that.  That takes care of the QInputDialog problem.  I'm still having trouble with QMessageBox.  I've tried using mkDialog.overrideWindowFlags(mkDialog.windowFlags()).  That can get rid of the "?", but I get the error: "QWidget: Incompatible window flags: the window can't be on top and on bottom at the same time".  The entire gui then goes behind every other window and I can't get it back on top.  I've tried setting the top window flag after the override, but no luck.

Comment: Maybe you should read through all the answers in the other question you linked to. The accepted answer isn't always the most useful one.

Comment: I did read through them all.  Solutions 1-3 didn't work.  Solutions 4-6 I don't understand.

Comment: By default, `QMessageBox` does not show the `What's This` question mark. Which version of PyQt4 are you using? If any of the widgets set a value using `setWhatsThis` then the question mark appears. This seems to be a bug/feature of your Window Decoration or a PyQt4 bug.

Comment: I am using PyQt 4.11.4.  It did seem odd that examples with QMessageBox didn't show the question mark, but they came up when I used it.