# Standard (?) button in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

How can i manipulate this button [img 1], which automaticly created in my project?

Interested function:

1. Delete;
2. Open new window with help;

[image]

Comment: Your question is rather unclear. Could you provide a [MCVE], or at least describe the minimal steps to create a new application, which has that?

Comment: I _think_ this is a duplicate, but not completely sure http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81627/how-can-i-hide-delete-the-help-button-on-the-title-bar-of-a-qt-dialog

Comment: In case this is a duplicate of just that, see [`Qt::WindowContextHelpButtonHint` in Qt docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#WindowType-enum).

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall The question is not about hiding the button, but how to use it.

Comment: @BenjaminT, maybe, but by "manipulating the button" (as the OP phrased it) I personally understand hiding/showing/moving the button/etc. Anyway, I'm not entirely sure and that's why I haven't closed this as a duplicate.

Comment: Actually there are two questions here and I guess it wouldn't be dumb to split them. The question "How can I hide ? ("What's this?") button in Qt?" could be marked as a [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81627/how-can-i-hide-delete-the-help-button-on-the-title-bar-of-a-qt-dialog), while the "How to override the "What's this?" button behavior in Qt" would get the answer "You can't"

Answer (score 2):

If you want to remove that button us the following in your dialog constructor:

```
setWindowFlags(windowFlags() & ~Qt::WindowContextHelpButtonHint);
```

See [`QWidget::setWindowFlags()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#windowFlags-prop) and [`Qt::WindowFlags`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#WindowType-enum) in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

The standard "?" button allows the user to enter a "What's this?" mode.

Quoting Qt documentation:

> "What's This?" help is part of an application's online help system,
>   and provides users with information about the functionality and usage
>   of a particular widget. "What's This?" help texts are typically longer
>   and more detailed than tooltips, but generally provide less
>   information than that supplied by separate help windows.

If you want to simply show help, have a looke at `QWidget::setWhatsThis(const QString &)`.

If you want to do more advanced things, have a look at the `QWhatsThis` class [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwhatsthis.html). Basically you need to catch `QEvent::WhatsThis` events and implement the behavior you want.

On a side note, software behavior are standardized and users do not expect strange behaviors. You should not make your software behave in an unexpected way. Example: the "X" button in the title bar should close the window and/or close the application, it should not do anything else. This is called [the principle of least astonishment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment)